# How to Distribute MongoDB Service with Program

Tags: python, mongodb

So I am creating a local Python script which I plan to export as an executable. However, this script is in need of a MongoDB instances that runs in the background as a service or daemon. How could one possibly include this MongoDB service along with their own ported application?

I have this configuration manually installed on my own computer with a MongoDB database installed as a local Windows service, and Python where my script adds and removes to the database as some events are fired. Is there any possible way to distribute this setup without manual installation of Python and MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include installations of all your utilities, I recommend [pynsist](http://pynsist.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It'll allow you to make a Windows installer that will make your code launchable as an app on the clients system, and include any other files and/or folders that you want.

Answer (score 0):

[Py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org) converts python scripts and their dependencies into Windows executable files. It has some limitations, but may work for your application.

You might also get away with not installing mongo, by embedding something like this in your application: https://github.com/Softmotions/ejdb. This may require you to rewrite your data access code.

If you can't or don't do that, then you could have all your clients share a multi-tenant mongo that you host someplace in the cloud.

Finally, if you can't or won't convert your python script to a standalone exe with an embedded database, and you don't want to host a shared mongo instance for your clients,  there are legions of software installation makers that make deploying mongo, python, setting up an execution environment, creating services, etc, pretty easy. Some are free, some cost money. A long list can be found here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Comment: Does `PouchDB` run continuously as a background service?

Comment: It is embedded in your application code. There is no server.

Comment: I'd like to stick with MongoDB if possible. Do you have any ideas how I can install it as a service?

Comment: I was actually mistaken, pouch is an an embedded version of couch, not mongo. There doesn't appear to be a good solution for embedding mongo in python application. I will revise my answer.

Comment: I think I'm going to use [`Tiny DB`](https://tinydb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) instead. Thanks for the help though.